# Excluding HTML ruby tags from copy/paste

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm using ruby tags to add pinyin. For example:

```
<p>
    <ruby>与<rt>yǔ</rt></ruby><ruby>摩<rt>mó</rt></ruby><ruby>拜<rt>bài</rt></ruby><ruby>单<rt>dān</rt></ruby><ruby>车<rt>chē</rt></ruby><ruby>推<rt>tuī</rt></ruby><ruby>出<rt>chū</rt></ruby><ruby>的<rt>de</rt></ruby>...
</p>
```

When I try to copy this, I copy the pinyin too:

```
与yǔ摩mó拜bài单dān车chē推tuī出chū的
```

I want to exclude the pinyin from being copied. E.g. I would want to copy/paste a sentence into Google Translate. Is there a way to do so without using Javascript?

I tried the `user-select` CSS property and `unselectable` HTML attribute, but none of them work.

This will be used in a Chrome extension, so only Chrome support is needed.

Comment: Can you share how you tried to use `user-select`?

Comment: @torazaburo I added it to the `rt` element. The pinyin wasn't being visually selected, but they were being copied.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a pseudo element:

```css
    
    rt:before {
      content: attr(data-rt);
    }
```

```html
    <p>
        <ruby>与<rt data-rt="yǔ"></rt></ruby><ruby>摩<rt data-rt="mó"></rt></ruby><ruby>拜<rt data-rt="bài"></rt></ruby>...
    </p>
```